# How Do I export Product SKU in Magento based on Manufacturer using PHPmyadmin

Tags: magento, phpmyadmin

How Do I export Product SKU in Magento based on Manufacturer using PHPmyadmin.

I am having trouble finding the correct tables and I to be honest I haven't coded sql in years any help?

Answer (score 0):

In magento maybe is not the best way to deal with SQL directly. In my opinion, the best way to extract something is via magento API. So, in your case you may try a script like that:

```
<?php

// Load Up Magento Core
define('MAGENTO', realpath(''));
require_once(MAGENTO . '/app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', 4); // integer - the id of manufacturer you want to extract, you can find it in admin panel with view source code

$productCollection->load();

foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    echo $product->getSku().'</br>';
}

?>
```

The above code will output a list with Product SKUs based on manufacturer ID.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Dpapanik the issue I have faced in the past with running Magneto scripts to get my SKU's is that because I have 1.4 million SKU's the site is always timing out/crashing this is why I though PHPmyadmin & SQL would be more rebust. I have just remembered I need this to also be filtered by Attribute set and manufacturer specifically spareparts